# Составление регулярного выражения

Tags: php, регулярные-выражения

Помогите составить регулярное выражение из этой строки

```
1-3 суток — 6300 руб./сутки
```

Как лучше сделать, что бы регуляка брала текст между `1-3 суток` и `руб./сутки`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Если Вас правильно понял, то Вам нужна цена, вот сходу накидал, [посмотрите](http://gskinner.com/RegExr/?37t84)

```
/(\d{1,})(?=\s*руб)/g
```

Но, если понимать Ваш пост буквально :), то вот [еще вариант](http://regexr.com/?37t87)

```
/(?<=суток)(.*)(?=\s*руб)/g
```